# in .net maui blazor hybrid how to use camera to take frames

Tags: android, .net, blazor, artificial-intelligence, maui

in .net maui blazor hybrid how to use camera to take frame to use in object detection

```
<button>scan</button>
```

on click on this button the camera page is opened and it make a frame on objects that were detected by the ML model